# What is the tag helper equivalent of Html.EditorFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

If I use `Html.EditorFor` on a property of type string then the generated element is by default an `<input>` of type 'text'.

Alternatively, if the property has the attribute `[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]` then `Html.EditorFor` generates a `<textarea>`.

If I'm using tag helpers, however, then I have to choose the element type for myself, e.g. `<input asp-for='MyProperty' />`. This can use information about the property to determine the input's type (text, date, email etc), but will always generate an `<input>`, never a `<textarea>`, even if I have the `[DataType]` attribute.

This seems to go against the idea that I can make the change from single line to multiline in one place: the model. Now I have to go through all relevant views and make the change myself.

It seems to me perfectly possible that I could write my own tag helper that could look at the property attributes and decide whether to generate an `<input>` or `<textarea>`, but I can't find any reference to a predefined one.

Is there such a predefined tag helper, and if not, is there a reason why?

Comment: That's the whole point of it. When you're in the view and use `EditorFor` you want to trust the framework to choose the proper "editor" for you (input, textarea, using date/time picker etc.) . When you want more control you directly write the html tag you want in t his specific situation in the view itself. read if you want it appear a textarea in a specific view, then just write `<textarea asp-for="MyProperty"></textarea>`

Comment: An yes, you can write your write your own that if that will help your specific case, it can be as simple as some expression tree magic and passing that to EditorFor inside the tag helper. But whats wrong with `EditorFor`, except that "it looks like code and not html"?

Comment: I'd disagree about that being the whole point. If you want to have more precise control than `Html.EditorFor` gives you, then you use `Html.TextAreaFor` etc and tag helpers are irrelevant. The point of tag helpers is that they are a more convenient syntax than Html helpers, but there seems no equivalent of the `EditorFor` helper.

Answer (score 2):

The new way of using tag helper equivalent of Html.EditorFor is just by Using The Old HtmlHelper Inside Tag Helper itself. Take a look at this blog and you might find what you need or use my code instead. http://blog.techdominator.com/article/using-html-helper-inside-tag-helpers.html

```
 [HtmlTargetElement("editor", TagStructure = TagStructure.WithoutEndTag, 
    Attributes = ForAttributeName + "," + TemplateAttributeName)]
public class EditorTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private IHtmlHelper _htmlHelper;

    private const string ForAttributeName = "asp-for";
    private const string TemplateAttributeName = "asp-template";

    [HtmlAttributeName(ForAttributeName)]
    public ModelExpression For { get; set; }


    [HtmlAttributeName(TemplateAttributeName)]
    public string Template { get; set; }

    [ViewContext]
    [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    public EditorTagHelper(IHtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        _htmlHelper = htmlHelper;
    }

    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        if (output == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(output));

        output.SuppressOutput();

        (_htmlHelper as IViewContextAware).Contextualize(ViewContext);

        output.Content.SetHtmlContent(_htmlHelper.Editor(For.Name, Template));

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I used this code for an input element, I found that my form validators (FluentValidation) were no longer triggering. Any idea why that would be?

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, some of what you discuss is actually part of the `InputTagHelper`. It will dynamically switch between different input types based on the property type (checkbox for bools, etc.). However, as you indicated, it will only ever generate an input, as it's explicitly an *input* taghelper. There's an entirely different taghelper for textareas. It is *technically* possible to create a custom tag helper to achieve what you want, but there's a good deal of work that goes into that. For a reference, see the [source for `InputTagHelper`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/InputTagHelper.cs). At this time, it's not possible to call other tag helpers from a tag helper, so you would need to basically merge the entire code for `InputTagHelper` with that of [`TextAreaTagHelper`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/TextAreaTagHelper.cs) into a custom tag helper. You could potentially save yourself a little work by inheriting your custom tag helper from `InputTagHelper` and then overriding `Process` to call `base.Process()` and then customizing the output. However, again, this is more complicated than a simple answer here can go into.

Long and short, yes, this is achievable with a custom tag helper, but it's going to require some work. Personally, I think it's a bit more work than it's worth, considering it's just one case: switching input with textarea for a multiline input, and you can technically still use `EditorFor` if your prefer.

If you want to go down this path, Microsoft has [an article/tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring) that will give you a good start. Other than that, just study the source for the existing helpers.

Comment: It's not just textareas though, that's merely an example. `Html.Editor` will also select different output on the basis of the `UIHint` attribute.

Comment: `UIHint` is an entirely different beast, though. In `EditorFor` this causes an entirely different template to be loaded in, as `EditorFor` is what's referred to as a "templated helper". Tag helpers are *not* templated helpers. If you need such functionality, you should just stick to `EditorFor`.

Answer (score 0):

Up until now there is no tag helper to achieve this but you can create you own similar to this.

```
    [HtmlTargetElement("editor-for")]
    public class EditorForTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        private const string TemplateValuesDictionaryName = "template-all-data";
        private const string HtmlAttributesDictionaryName = "html-all-data";

        private IDictionary<string, object> _templateValues;
        private IDictionary<string, string> _htmlAttributes;

        public ModelExpression For
        {
            get; set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Display template name  to use for rendering
        /// </summary>
        public string Template
        {
            get; set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Additional parameters for the template.
        /// </summary>
        [HtmlAttributeName(TemplateValuesDictionaryName, DictionaryAttributePrefix = "template-")]
        public IDictionary<string, object> TemplateValues
        {
            get
            {
                if (_templateValues == null)
                    _templateValues = new Dictionary<string, object>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

                return _templateValues;
            }
            set
            {
                _templateValues = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Additional htmlattributes for the control template
        /// </summary>
        [HtmlAttributeName(HtmlAttributesDictionaryName, DictionaryAttributePrefix = "html-")]
        public IDictionary<string, string> HtmlAttributes
        {
            get
            {
                if (_htmlAttributes == null)
                    _htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

                return _htmlAttributes;
            }
            set
            {
                _htmlAttributes = value;
            }
        }


        [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
        [ViewContext]
        public ViewContext ViewContext
        {
            get; set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new <see cref="DisplayForTagHelper"/>.
        /// </summary>        
        public EditorForTagHelper()
        {
        }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            if (context == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

            if (output == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(output));


            if (For != null)
            {
                TemplateValues.AddOrUpdate("htmlAttributes", HtmlAttributes.ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => (object)e.Value));
                var control = ViewContext.GenerateEditor(For,For.Name, Template, TemplateValues);
                output.Content.AppendHtml(control);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This example needs updating, as there is no longer a "GenerateEditor" method on ViewContext, neither does a IDictionary have a AddOrUpdate method.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the answer provided by 'Prince Owusu', I have modified it so that the 'Template' property is optional:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("editor", TagStructure = TagStructure.WithoutEndTag,
    Attributes = ForAttributeName)]
public class EditorTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private readonly IHtmlHelper _htmlHelper;

    private const string ForAttributeName = "asp-for";
    private const string TemplateAttributeName = "asp-template";

    [HtmlAttributeName(ForAttributeName)]
    public ModelExpression For { get; set; }


    [HtmlAttributeName(TemplateAttributeName)]
    public string Template { get; set; }

    [ViewContext]
    [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    public EditorTagHelper(IHtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        _htmlHelper = htmlHelper;
    }

    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        if (output == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(output));

        if (!output.Attributes.ContainsName(nameof(Template)))
        {
            output.Attributes.Add(nameof(Template), Template);
        }

        output.SuppressOutput();

        (_htmlHelper as IViewContextAware).Contextualize(ViewContext);

        output.Content.SetHtmlContent(_htmlHelper.Editor(For.Name, Template));

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

This would be used something like this:

```
<editor asp-for="MyModel.EmailAddress"/>
```

Which is equivalent of:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.MyModel.EmailAddress)
```

In my usage example, I have not specified a template so ASP.NET will look for a template that matches the type of my 'EmailAddress' property. If I wanted to specify a template I would use it like this :

```
<editor asp-for="MyModel.EmailAddress" asp-template="MyEmailTemplate"/>
```