Asp.net Core Razor Pages - Custom TagHelpers & Boiler plate CRUD code
I'm sure this problem has been faced many times before.
I have a lot of CRUD forms, so I have a lot of repeated boiler plate code.
e.g.
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="MyModel.Property1" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="MyModel.Property1" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="MyModel.Property1" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

The above code being repeated time and time again per property, per form. Always looks the same (except if it's a dropdown for example).
I have managed to get something repeatable running with EditorTemplates, but this feels clunky. I'd need a different template per property type etc.
This requires running:
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyModel.Property1, "_MyString")
I feel @Html. is almost discouraged in Razor Pages and the solution should be elsewhere.
I've spent far too long looking into getting a custom TagHelper setup and working, and I don't think it's possible. You can create your own TagHelpers and use TagBuilder, but you then lose all of the logic which is inside the InputTagHelper etc.
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.TagHelpers/src/InputTagHelper.cs
It needs to utilize the Input and Label TagHelpers as there is a lot of logic for example around property type in the InputTagHelper as per the above link. You can't seemingly use these.
I'm looking for a really generic way to cut down on my boiler plate code, and was hoping there might be a magic pill?
Edited to say - you also used to be able to do this in MVC which you can't do via Razor Pages, without creating per model.
public static IHtmlContent MyEditorFor<TModel, TResult>(
    this IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression,
    string templateName = "MyDefaultTemplateName")
{
    return htmlHelper.EditorFor(expression, templateName);
}


This seems like a job for partials?

My team went down this path ages ago with MVC (so the tech doesn't directly apply). My advice is to make sure you give yourself customization options. The ability to add classes, attributes, data attributes, etc to each element in your group. That was initially overlooked in out solution and it came back to bite us.

Maybe like https://stackoverflow.com/a/56110731/4139809 ?

Here is a whole working demo you could follow:
Create the Custom Tag Helper
[HtmlTargetElement("div-group", Attributes = "asp-for")]
public class DivGroupTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private const string ForAttributeName = "asp-for";
    private IHtmlGenerator _htmlGenerator;
    public DivGroupTagHelper(IHtmlGenerator htmlGenerator)
    {
        _htmlGenerator = htmlGenerator;
    }
    [HtmlAttributeName(ForAttributeName)]
    public ModelExpression For { get; set; }

    [HtmlAttributeName("class")]
    public string CssClass { get; set; }

    [HtmlAttributeName("label-class")]
    public string LabelCssClass { get; set; }

    [HtmlAttributeName("input-class")]
    public string InputCssClass { get; set; }

    [HtmlAttributeName("validation-class")]
    public string ValidationCssClass { get; set; }
    [HtmlAttributeNotBound]

    [ViewContext]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.TagName = "div";
        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("class", "form-group " + CssClass);

        // Create a context and output for the label
        var labelContext = new TagHelperContext(new TagHelperAttributeList(), new Dictionary<object, object>(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
        var labelOutput = new TagHelperOutput("label", new TagHelperAttributeList(), (useCachedResult, encoder) => Task.FromResult<TagHelperContent>(new DefaultTagHelperContent()));

        var labelTagHelper = new LabelTagHelper(_htmlGenerator)
        {
            For = For,
            ViewContext = ViewContext
        };

        await labelTagHelper.ProcessAsync(labelContext, labelOutput);
        labelOutput.AddClass("control-label", HtmlEncoder.Default);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(LabelCssClass)) labelOutput.AddClass(LabelCssClass, HtmlEncoder.Default);

        //Create a context and output for the input

        var inputContext = new TagHelperContext(new TagHelperAttributeList(), new Dictionary<object, object>(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
        var inputOutput = new TagHelperOutput("input", new TagHelperAttributeList(), (useCachedResult, encoder) => Task.FromResult<TagHelperContent>(new DefaultTagHelperContent()));

        var inputTagHelper = new InputTagHelper(_htmlGenerator)
        {
            For = For,
            ViewContext = ViewContext
        };

        await inputTagHelper.ProcessAsync(inputContext, inputOutput);
        inputOutput.AddClass("form-control", HtmlEncoder.Default);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(InputCssClass)) inputOutput.AddClass(InputCssClass, HtmlEncoder.Default);

        // Create a context and output for the validation message
        var validationContext = new TagHelperContext(new TagHelperAttributeList(), new Dictionary<object, object>(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
        var validationOutput = new TagHelperOutput("span", new TagHelperAttributeList(), (useCachedResult, encoder) => Task.FromResult<TagHelperContent>(new DefaultTagHelperContent()));

        var validationTagHelper = new ValidationMessageTagHelper(_htmlGenerator)
        {
            For = For,
            ViewContext = ViewContext
        };

        await validationTagHelper.ProcessAsync(validationContext, validationOutput);
        validationOutput.AddClass("text-danger", HtmlEncoder.Default);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ValidationCssClass)) validationOutput.AddClass(ValidationCssClass, HtmlEncoder.Default);

        // Append the generated content to the output
        output.Content.AppendHtml(labelOutput);
        output.Content.AppendHtml(inputOutput);
        output.Content.AppendHtml(validationOutput);
    }      
}

Add the Tag Helper registration in your _ViewImports.cshtml file
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, YourNamespace

Use the custom Tag Helper in your Razor Pages
@page
@model IndexModel

<form method="post">
    <div-group asp-for="Password"></div-group>
    <div-group asp-for="Email"></div-group>
    <input type="submit" value="Create"/>
</form>
@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}


Thanks - works well.
After this line:
await inputTagHelper.ProcessAsync(inputContext, inputOutput);
I'm thinking about this for different date type css needed, unless you can think of anything better?
var propertyType = For.ModelExplorer.ModelType.Name;
if (propertyType == "Boolean")
{
inputOutput.AddClass("form-control-input", HtmlEncoder.Default);
}
else
{
inputOutput.AddClass("form-control", HtmlEncoder.Default);
}

I'm also looking for a way of replacing this if you have any ideas?







Hi @HelpMe, of course you can use the code by what you said:var propertyType = For.ModelExplorer.ModelType.Name; if (propertyType == "Boolean") { inputOutput.AddClass("form-control-input", HtmlEncoder.Default); } else { inputOutput.AddClass("form-control", HtmlEncoder.Default); } 

For another way, you can see i define HtmlAttribute like LabelCssClass,InputCssClass etc. You can also define the code:  <div-group asp-for="Password"  input-class="form-control"></div-group><div-group asp-for="Flag" input-class="form-control-input"></div-group> instead of using inputOutput.AddClass.
